same url different response on Chrome and firefox
i have the following url, the Chrome and Firefox with different response.
https://example.com/sell
on Firefox its ok
on Chrome it gives somthing like:
https://example.com/kunden/homepages/45/d913608981/htdocs/example/index.php/kunden/homepages/45/d913608981/htdocs/example/index.php/kunden/homepages/45/d913608981/htdocs/example/index.php/kunden/homepages/45/d913608981/htdocs/example/index.php/kunden/homepages/45/d913608981/htdocs/example/index.php/kunden/homepages/45/d913608981/htdocs/example/index.php/kunden/homepages/45/d913608981/htdocs/example/index.php/kunden/homepages/45/d913608981/htdocs/example/index.php/kunden/homepages/45/d913608981/htdocs/example/index.php/kunden/homepages/45/d913608981/htdocs/example/index.php/kunden/homepages/45/d913608981/htdocs/example/index.php/kunden/homepages/45/d913608981/htdocs/example/index.php/kunden/homepages/45/d913608981/htdocs/example/index.php/kunden/homepages/45/d913608981/htdocs/example/index.php/kunden/homepages/45/d913608981/htdocs/example/index.php/kunden/homepages/45/d913608981/htdocs/example/index.php/kunden/homepages/45/d913608981/htdocs/example/index.php/kunden/homepages/45/d913608981/htdocs/example/index.php/kunden/homepages/45/d913608981/htdocs/example/index.php/sell
my .htaccess file is something like:
# Disable directory browsing
Options -Indexes

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Rewrite engine
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Turning on the rewrite engine is necessary for the following rules and features.
# FollowSymLinks must be enabled for this to work.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On

    # If you installed CodeIgniter in a subfolder, you will need to
    # change the following line to match the subfolder you need.
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase
    RewriteBase /

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
#   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %1 [L,R=301]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,L]

    # Rewrite "www.example.com -> example.com"
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

    # Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    # such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    # request to the front controller, index.php
#   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#   RewriteRule ^([\s\S]*)$ index.php/$1 [L,NC,QSA]

    # Ensure Authorization header is passed along
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    ErrorDocument 404 index.php
</IfModule>

# Disable server signature start
ServerSignature Off
# Disable server signature end
sETeNV ci_environment DEVELOPMENT
enter code here


Have you cleared any cookies? What happens if you try "incognito" mode in either browser?

after clearing cookies the same result, but "incognito" mode its ok.

clearing cookies, and restart the chrome now its ok, thank you.

how can I close this question? the problem is solved.

You could delete the question, but better ist to write an answer yourself that might help others who stumble over the same issue.

clearing cookies, and restart the chrome solved the problem.
